# How big is Starfleet (at the top)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, starfleet-rank, statistics

During the TNG years (or at any point you like until the end of DS9), how many active Starfleet officers were there overall, at a given time, of the ranks:

- Fleet Admiral
- Admiral
- Vice-Admiral

?

Note: I realize Fleet Admiral could be either a separate rank or an awarded title; I mean the separate rank.

Comment: Closely related, possibly a dupe of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95050/how-many-admirals-are-in-starfleet

Comment: @Praxis: That question is very close, but the answers there don't answer my question (nor that question itself).

Comment: @einpoklum : That answer certainly does answer that question and yours.  We don’t have a canon answer as to how many active admirals there were during *TNG*, but one can arrive at estimates / lower bounds.  Furthermore, the wording of the two questions — how many admirals are there in the *TNG* era in Starfleet — are nearly identical.  I’ve seen questions / answers further apart than these closed as dupes.  If you want to make your question about fleet and vice-admirals specifically or disambiguate them in some other way, I would happily re-open. :-)

Comment: @Praxis: No, it's fine. leave it closed.