# Is there an official process to remove a high-ranking Starfleet officer for misconduct?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, starfleet-rank, starfleet-command

In DS9's Paradise Lost episode (season 04, episode 12), the plot is heavy with Starfleet intrigue: Sisko discovers that Admiral Leyton is plotting to take over control of Earth and put it under a military rule. His options seem limited to convincing the President of the United Federation of Planets of the plot, or convince captains working for Leyton to stop obeying orders.

The fact that these seem to be the only options seems suboptimal. Are there no other high-ranking Starfleet officers (fleet admirals, maybe?) in the [chain of command](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104784/whats-the-command-structure-at-the-top-of-starfleet) between one of (presumably, [many](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95050/how-many-admirals-are-in-starfleet)) admirals and the president of the Federation? Is there no official process (involving [Internal Affairs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Internal_Affairs), perhaps) to deal with claims of misconduct?

Comment: The admirals report to the boss admiral who reports to the President. I'd imagine that the President could (theoretically) order the demotion or dismissal of someone below them in the chain of command.

Comment: Yeah, it kinda sucks when high-ranking officials go off the rails and only “suboptimal” options are available to get things back under control.  A circumstance rife with intrigue indeed.